# Web API attribute routing and validation - possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-web-api, modelstate

I'm trying to combine attribute-based routing in Web API with model validation.  I simply can't get it to work as I would expect.

```
class MyRequestModel
{
    [DefaultValue("DefaultView")]
    public string viewName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string something { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("myroute/{id:minlength(2)}")]
public IHttpActionResult Test(string id, [FromUri]MyRequestModel request)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return BadRequest(ModelState); }
    // process here...
    return Json( /* result */ );
}
```

Although `something` is validated correctly, I have some issues:

- When I specify only a `something` parameter value, that comes through OK, but `viewName` comes through as `null`, and yet the model state is valid - I would expect the default value since nothing was specified
- When I specify a blank `viewName` parameter (`?something=x&viewName=`), it comes through as `"DefaultView"`, and the model state is valid - I would expect it as a blank string as specified
- If I remove `[FromUri]`, `request` comes through consistently as `null`
- There seems to be no way to include route parameters as part of the model (i.e., `id` must be a parameter, not part of the request model), meaning - I think - that I can't use model state validation on routing parameters

I was validating parameters manually, but figured I would try to leverage the pre-built functionality and power of model state validation.  I will admit however with the masses of overlapping and sometimes contradictory documentation around MVC, Web API and various versions thereof, I'm unable to find any single source of truth - just quick starter guides on the ASP.NET site.  Pointers here would be very welcome, too!

Is it just not possible to combine these things in the way I'm expecting?  Does `DefaultValueAttribute` not do what I think it does?  Can I not validate all parameters to the controller somehow - including those appearing as a part of the routing?

Comment: See my more specific question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30482415/web-api-model-validation-and-default-values - this question concerns routing and validation, which I have resolved.  Just the default value issue remains!

Comment: Why don't you delete this question, that is in fact too complex to answer? Besides, IMO, you've got the right answer in your other question.